# Tkinter error after upgrading to OS X 10.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, osx-mavericks

I have a Tkinter application that ran fine in OS X 10.7.5.  Recently, when I upgraded to 10.9.2, it ceased to run, throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "roiTracker.py", line 5127, in <module>
   startTracker(filename=filename)
 File "roiTracker.py", line 5111, in startTracker
   tk = TK.Tk()
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1745, in _init_
   self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Tkinter and python versions:

```
user:Desktop user$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Tkinter
>>> Tkinter.__version__
'$Revision: 81008 $'
>>> exit()
```

Contents of `$DISPLAY` variable:

```
user:Desktop user$ echo $DISPLAY

user:Desktop user$
```

As per [this similar-sounding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725694/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-for-new), I tried

```
launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist
```

and got

```
Couldn't stat("/Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist"): No such file or directory
nothing found to load
```

Not sure if that was naive or not - I'm pretty ignorant about how the windowing backends work.

I am running all of these commands locally.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Might it be this problem? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725694/tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-for-new

Comment: Do you have XQuartz installed? - https://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Comment: Not that I know of - if you don't mind, can you explain why I need that for 10.9 but I didn't need it for 10.7?

Comment: According to http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5293 "X11 is no longer included with OS X", it may have been included with 10.7, I don't remember exactly when they stopped including it.