# Using matplotlib on headless Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssh, matplotlib

I have a headless Ubuntu 14.04 Server that I connect to remotely using SSH. I want to use matplotlib and have plots appear at the ssh client. For example, I would connect using:

```
ssh -X name@server.com
```

And then from a Python console, I want this to produce a plot in a window:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

I have installed matplotlib in my virtualenv, and I ran `sudo apt-get install python-gtk2`, but the plot still doesn't appear. I assume I'm missing lots of packages. What is a fairly minimal set of X-related packages I could install to make this work? I do NOT want to install `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined

Comment: That is not the same question. I explicitly WANT to use an X backend, while the accepted answer on the other question works around that requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that, the other question comes up so often I pattern-matched too aggressively.  Can you get other gui programs to launch and do you have an xserver running on the remote machine?

Comment: Thanks for untagging! After some trial and error with x-related packages, I can get xeyes to run over ssh. The problem seems to be that when I `pip install matplotlib`, it doesn't recognize that pygtk is installed. Therefore, the only backend that gets installed is agg. The problem might be that pygtk is installed site-wide rather than in my venv, but I have site packages enabled for this venv. Thus, `import pygtk` works fine. But the pip installer doesn't seem to realize I have it installed.

Comment: @10flow - It's possible the auto-detection of which backends to build is being rather quirky in your specific case.  A workaround is to manually specify which backends you want when building matplotlib.  You'll need to download the source (e.g. tarball) and build things manually (or use something pre-built with a gui backend like anaconda/canopy).  To specify the backends, cp `setup.cfg.template` to `setup.cfg` and edit it accordingly (the file itself has extensive documentation).  Also, if it can't build the gtk backend, you'll get more informative errors, instead of just skipping it.

Comment: @JoeKington forcing gtk backend didn't work, but I managed to get PyQt4 installed site-wide, and then forcing matplotlib to install qt4agg backend worked! I'm going to figure out the minimal set of things I had to do and put an answer here. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server, but it was painful! The tricky part is definitely virtualenv. I finally had luck using the Qt4 backend, which I was only able to install via the Ubuntu package and then had to symlink it into my virtualenv. So here's the step-by-step process...

First install the pre-reqs and hack PyQt4 into your virtualenv:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xauth x11-apps python-qt4 
$ ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4 /path/to/myvenv/lib/python2.7/PyQt4
```

Now manually download and install SIP (http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/intro) with your venv activated, as follows:

```
$ tar xzf sip-4.16.4.tar.gz
$ cd sip-4.16.4
$ python configure.py
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Next, download matplotlib source tarball and modify the setup configuration to force it to install Qt4 backend:

```
$ tar xzf matplotlib-1.4.2.tar.gz
$ cp matplotlib-1.4.2/setup.cfg.template matplotlib-1.4.2/setup.cfg
```

Now edit `setup.cfg` near line 68 to read:

```
qt4agg = True
```

Matplotlib will now install cleanly in your venv:

```
$ pip install -e matplotlib-1.4.2/
```

Now you can SSH using the `-X` flag and plots will load remotely!