# python matplotlib save graph without showing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to create a histogram and save it to a file without showing it on the screen. The  piece of code I have now is showing the figure by default and I cannot find any way to suppress showing the figure. I have tried pyplot.hist(nrs) as well, with the same problem.

```
import math, time, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, pylab; 
import numpy as np; 

nrs = [1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0]
freq,bins = np.histogram(nrs)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100); 
freq = np.append(freq, [0.0])
graph = fig.add_subplot(111);
x = graph.bar(bins, freq)

fig.savefig( "test.png")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour(matplotlib 1.3.1).  What version are you using?

Comment: are you sure you don't have `plt.show()` or `fig.show()` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Just save this as a .py script and run it with `python script.py`. This should work. The only way you could be getting a figure without calling `plt.show()` is with interactive mode in IPython.

Comment: You want to use one of the headless backends (ex `Agg`).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined/3054314#3054314 for an example (slightly different issue there, but same solution).

Comment: You might be using an interactive client (IPython). `plt.ioff()` would turn *autoploting* off.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you tcasewell, adding

```
import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

Before importing pyplot solved the problem.