# Matplotlib: check if undefined DISPLAY

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh

Sometimes I run my script via ssh. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) told me to set up

```
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('Agg') # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

when I get the `undefined SCREEN` error by running the script via ssh. However with that preamble I cannot view the graphs interactively when I run the script on my local machine.

What's the condition to check if the screen is defined? I'd like to do

```
if SCREEN == None:
  matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

How's the proper code for that, how can I check this?

Comment: And have you connected with [`ssh -X`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303165/1771479)?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an easiest way to do this is to check 'DISPLAY' environment variable

```
import os

# 'DISPLAY' will be something like this ':0'
# on your local machine, and None otherwise
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY') is None:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
```