# Python Saving PNG in Terminal vs IPython Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am writing a basic Python module which contains a function that plots some data from a Pandas DataFrame.  The problem is that I expect users to call this function from *both* the interactive shell *and* IPython notebooks.  Unfortunately, our interactive shell environment does not have any valid DISPLAY options for matplotlib to use, so I want my function (or the full module) to behave slightly different depending on which environment it is loaded into.  (E.g., the default is show the plot without saving in IPython, and save the plot without showing in the shell).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined) gives me a partial answer, in that I can explicitly tell users to write `matplotlib.use('Agg')` before they ever import my module, but surely there is a more automated backend way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking if you are running into the situation (empty `$DISPLAY`) and default users to the `Agg` backend, rather than asking them to do so.

```
def configure_matplotlib():
   import os
   if 'DISPLAY' not in os.environ:
      if matplotlib.get_backend() != 'Agg':
          matplotlib.use('Agg')


import matplotlib
configure_matplotlib()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
```

Now `matplotlib.use` has no effect once `pyplot` has been imported, but if your users have already done so, they probably have a working configuration anyway.