# matplotlib error on VNC/xfce on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, xlib

When I run matplotlib in python, I got the error below:

[image: error]

I am running VNC (xfce4) on Ubuntu 14.04. The plot is shown, however, the application will stop.
I tried to search solutions but no success. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need interactive plots?  What backend are you using?

Comment: I do not need interactive plots. I am using xfce

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined/3054314#3054314 Slightly different error, but same solution.

Comment: Thanks! However, I do want to plot and update a window on the fly when the application is running...always save to disk will generate too many images..