# Docker running Jupyter Notebook - `'no $DISPLAY environment variable'?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ssh, graph, docker

I am running a Docker container with Jupyter Notebook using:

`sudo nvidia-docker run -it -v /media/files:/files -p 8888:8888 -p 6001:6001 mybigdocker:latest`

And then connecting to it at `127.0.0.1:8888` in Chrome.

Everything works fine, except if I try to do anything with matplotlib, or any type of non-text output, where I get the error:

`TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`

I have tried adding `--env="DISPLAY"` and `--env=$DISPLAY` and `--env=":0"` with no avail.

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined That answer should help but what I think you need to do is `import matplotlib
# Force matplotlib to not use any Xwindows backend.
matplotlib.use('Agg')`

Comment: @Alastair looks like I still get the same problem when I run it in ipython notebook; but seems to work OK in console ipython.