# QxcbConnection error when Python matplotlib run as cron job

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib, cron

I have a plotting script that was scheduled to run as a cron job, but throws an error.  The script was written in Python 3.5, and an example is given below.

```
import pylab as pl

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax = fig.add_supblot(111)

ax.plot(range(10), range(10))
```

I was calling it in a bash script via the following line:
    ~/anaconda3/bin/ipython test.py

I got the following error in my cron report:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
/datadrive/cronjobs/test.sh: line 2:  1459 Aborted (core dumped) ~/anaconda3/bin/python ~/Desktop/test.py
```

I even tried calling directly from the crontab, but got the same error.

I have confirmed that I can run the script from the terminal.  Both of these work:

```
$ ~/anaconda3/bin/ipython ~/Desktop/test.py
$ bash /datadrive/cronjobs/test.sh
```

It seems the matplotlib does not like to be run under cron, but I cannot see why.  Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across a similar problem on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined).  The trick is to load in matplotlib before pylab and call matplotlib.use('Agg').  e.g.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pylab

etc. etc. etc.
```

Apparently, when running under a cron job there is not an active graphical backend (or something, I don't really understand that part).  Setting matplotlib's .use as "Agg" solves this.

Comment: this is probably the right answer. I removed my answer again because apparently you *can* start a python script with `ipython` it's just not recommended to do so

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be working remotely or wo screen add this to your bashrc:

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORM='offscreen'
```