# python matplotlib pyplot show failed after installing vnc?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, centos7, vnc

run in centos7, all was good before, after i install vnc-server, then plt.show() failed, i call show(), the program block and no response.

```
plt.plot( ... details that work and not the problem ... )
plt.show()
```

the error message:

```
QXcbConnection: XCB error: 148 (Unknown), sequence: 169, resource id: 0, major code: 140 (Unknown), minor code: 20
```

can anyone help? i have worked on this so many time, bothered me a lot

Thanks

Comment: Hope this could help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944024/using-matplotlib-on-non-0-mpi-rank-causes-qxcbconnection-could-not-connect-to), (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2373935)

Comment: @TavoGLC Thank you, that helps