# create png without show figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I built a small piece of code to plot some data.

I built it on my Oracle VirtualBox and it worked.

I moved it to production, and had the sys admin install the code and the libraries, etc.

Now the `matplotlib.pyplot` section is failing.

I tried a simple snippet

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
time = [0, 1, 2, 3]
position = [0, 100, 200, 300]
plt.plot(time, position)
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)')
plt.ylabel('Position (km)')
```

and get...

> qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display

I don't even want to see this on the screen, I just want to create a **png** for a web site.

How can the code be re-written to connect to the display?

Comment: You need to use the `agg` backend if you don't want to or cannot show your figure.

Comment: This post solved my issue!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined?rq=1

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  You were right, but I didn't understand you comment at the time until I found another post, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take off the "plt." and it will work

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
time = [0, 1, 2, 3]
position = [0, 100, 200, 300]
plot(time, position)
xlabel('Time (hr)')
ylabel('Position (km)')
```

Comment: I copied your code snippet.  Because no X I changed plot(time, position) to savefig('./books_read.png') and still get ^Cqt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display