# How to disable pyplot to access the environment variable DISPLAY

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to save a pyplot figure into a buffer and then base64 encoded so that I can embed it into a html body later.

```
def draw_picture():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3],[3, 4, 5])
    buf = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png")
    data = base64.b64encode(buf.getvalue()).decode("utf-8")
    return "<img src='data:image/png;base64,{data}'/>".format(data=data)
```

The first problem I met is that it always requires the environment variable `$DISPLAY` or I will get this error:

```
  File "/home/mals/bin/chart.py", line 30, in hello
    fig = plt.figure()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 533, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1046, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1745, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I was not trying to show the figure but why it still needs to read `$DISPLAY`?

The second problem is the statement `fig = plt.figure` takes 20 seconds!

Comment: Your main problem is solved by [generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined).

Comment: The problem is solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined