# Why is my matplotlib graph generating a Gtk-CRITICAL error?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gtk

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig('saved_figure.png')
```

Whenever I try to generate a basic matplotlib graph as a png I get the error:

```
(test.py:26168): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:14:27.436: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(test.py:26168): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:14:27.436: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed

(test.py:26168): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:14:27.436: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
Segmentation Fault
```

If it matters I think my server is a Solaris 10

Answer (score 0):

same solution as:
[Generating a PNG with matplotlib when DISPLAY is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined?rq=1)

the top answer which solved

```
import matplotlib
```

Force matplotlib to not use any XWindow backend.

```
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```